Next js Prisma SaaS notification app. My 2 registered users are visible in clerk, but do not appear in prisma studio
Initially, the problems arose because the author of the guide "pingpanda" connected the neon database and the jstack project template contains files tied to connecting to neon. I deleted the unnecessary file for neon (npm uninstall @neondatabase/serverless)
And changed other files so that they were not related to neon

My 2 registered users are visible in clerk (auth system), but do not appear in the database (prisma studio).
When logging in, the user is not redirected to the dashboard, as it should be, but the button and the ability to signout appear.
There are no errors in the terminal

GITHUB:
https://github.com/nikitodeon/pingpanda-ErrorProject.git
LOGS in Railway database:
2024-12-15 06:53:45.221 UTC [5] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.4 (Debian 16.4-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit

2024-12-15 06:53:45.221 UTC [5] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

2024-12-15 06:53:45.221 UTC [5] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

2024-12-15 06:53:45.371 UTC [5] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

2024-12-15 06:53:45.391 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-12-15 06:12:11 UTC


2024-12-15 06:53:45.431 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress

2024-12-15 06:53:45.435 UTC [28] LOG:  redo starts at 0/66E0140

2024-12-15 06:53:45.435 UTC [28] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/66E0228: expected at least 24, got 0

2024-12-15 06:53:45.435 UTC [28] LOG:  redo done at 0/66E01F0 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s

2024-12-15 06:53:45.440 UTC [26] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait

2024-12-15 06:53:45.450 UTC [26] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.003 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.012 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/66E0228, redo lsn=0/66E0228

2024-12-15 06:53:45.454 UTC [5] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections


///////////////////////////////////
No errors in prisma commands:
C:\Users\Julia\Documents\next-projects\ping-panda>npx prisma migrate dev --preview-feature
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "railway", schema "public" at "junction.proxy.rlwy.net:58056"  

Already in sync, no schema change or pending migration was found.

✔ Generated Prisma Client (v5.22.0) to .\node_modules\@prisma\client in 149ms
z
C:\Users\Julia\Documents\next-projects\ping-panda>npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "railway", schema "public" at "junction.proxy.rlwy.net:58056"  

The database is already in sync with the Prisma schema.

✔ Generated Prisma Client (v5.22.0) to .\node_modules\@prisma\client in 165ms
C:\Users\Julia\Documents\next-projects\ping-panda>npx prisma generate
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma

✔ Generated Prisma Client (v5.22.0) to .\node_modules\@prisma\client in 121ms

Start by importing your Prisma Client (See: https://pris.ly/d/importing-client)

Tip: Need your database queries to be 1000x faster? Accelerate offers you that and more: https://pris.ly/tip-2-accelerate
Mounting volume on: /var/lib/containers/railwayapp/bind-mounts/49595d90-aa32-4e74-b78b-2177e03bbc6a/vol_v8sv8mu4w007pafl

Certificate will not expire

 

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

auth-router.ts
import { db } from "@/db"
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs/server"
import { HTTPException } from "hono/http-exception"
import { router } from "../__internals/router"
import { publicProcedure } from "../procedures"

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"

export const authRouter = router({
  getDatabaseSyncStatus: publicProcedure.query(async ({ c, ctx }) => {
    const auth = await currentUser()

    if (!auth) {
      return c.json({ isSynced: false })
    }

    const user = await db.user.findFirst({
      where: { externalId: auth.id },
    })

    console.log("USER IN DB:", user)

    if (!user) {
      await db.user.create({
        data: {
          quotaLimit: 100,
          externalId: auth.id,
          email: auth.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress,
        },
      })
      return c.json({ isSynced: true })
    }

    return c.json({ isSynced: true })
  }),
})

// route.ts


route.ts
import { httpHandler } from "@/server"

export const runtime = "edge"

export { httpHandler as GET, httpHandler as POST }


schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id              String          @id @default(cuid())
  externalId      String?         @unique
  quotaLimit      Int
  plan            Plan            @default(FREE)
  email           String          @unique
  apiKey          String          @unique @default(cuid())
  discordId       String?
  createdAt       DateTime        @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime        @updatedAt
  events          Event[]
  EventCategories EventCategory[]
  Quota           Quota?

  @@index([email, apiKey])
}

model EventCategory {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  name      String
  color     Int
  emoji     String?
  userId    String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  events    Event[]
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  @@unique([name, userId])
}

model Event {
  id               String         @id @default(cuid())
  formattedMessage String
  userId           String
  name             String
  fields           Json
  deliveryStatus   DeliveryStatus @default(PENDING)
  createdAt        DateTime       @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime       @updatedAt
  eventCategoryId  String?
  EventCategory    EventCategory? @relation(fields: [eventCategoryId], references: [id])
  user             User           @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  @@index([createdAt])
}

model Quota {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  userId    String   @unique
  year      Int
  month     Int
  count     Int      @default(0)
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

enum Plan {
  FREE
  PRO
}

enum DeliveryStatus {
  PENDING
  DELIVERED
  FAILED
}


.env.example
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@junction.proxy.rlwy.net:58056/railway

NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=****. ..
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=****.. . 

page.tsx
"use client"

// synchronize auth status to database

import { Heading } from "@/components/heading"
import { LoadingSpinner } from "@/components/loading-spinner"
import { client } from "@/lib/client"
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { LucideProps } from "lucide-react"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import { useEffect } from "react"

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await client.auth.getDatabaseSyncStatus.$get()
      return await res.json()
    },
    queryKey: ["get-database-sync-status"],
    refetchInterval: (query) => {
      return query.state.data?.isSynced ? false : 1000
    },
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.isSynced) router.push("/dashboard")
  }, [data, router])

  return (
    <div className="flex w-full flex-1 items-center justify-center px-4">
      <BackgroundPattern className="absolute inset-0 left-1/2 z-0 -translate-x-1/2 opacity-75" />

      <div className="relative z-10 flex -translate-y-1/2 flex-col items-center gap-6 text-center">
        <LoadingSpinner size="md" />
        <Heading>Creating your account...</Heading>
        <p className="text-base/7 text-gray-600 max-w-prose">
          Just a moment while we set things up for you.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const BackgroundPattern = (props: LucideProps) => {
  return (
    <svg
      width="768"
      height="736"
      viewBox="0 0 768 736"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      className={props.className}
    >
      <mask
        id="mask0_5036_374506"
        style={{ maskType: "alpha" }}
        maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        x="0"
        y="-32"
        width="768"
        height="768"
      >
        <rect
          width="768"
          height="768"
          transform="translate(0 -32)"
          fill="url(#paint0_radial_5036_374506)"
        />
      </mask>
      <g mask="url(#mask0_5036_374506)">
        <g clipPath="url(#clip0_5036_374506)">
          <g clipPath="url(#clip1_5036_374506)">
            <line x1="0.5" y1="-32" x2="0.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="48.5" y1="-32" x2="48.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="96.5" y1="-32" x2="96.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="144.5" y1="-32" x2="144.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="192.5" y1="-32" x2="192.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="240.5" y1="-32" x2="240.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="288.5" y1="-32" x2="288.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="336.5" y1="-32" x2="336.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="384.5" y1="-32" x2="384.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="432.5" y1="-32" x2="432.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="480.5" y1="-32" x2="480.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="528.5" y1="-32" x2="528.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="576.5" y1="-32" x2="576.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="624.5" y1="-32" x2="624.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="672.5" y1="-32" x2="672.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line x1="720.5" y1="-32" x2="720.5" y2="736" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
          </g>
          <rect x="0.5" y="-31.5" width="767" height="767" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
          <g clipPath="url(#clip2_5036_374506)">
            <line y1="15.5" x2="768" y2="15.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="63.5" x2="768" y2="63.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="111.5" x2="768" y2="111.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="159.5" x2="768" y2="159.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="207.5" x2="768" y2="207.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="255.5" x2="768" y2="255.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="303.5" x2="768" y2="303.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="351.5" x2="768" y2="351.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="399.5" x2="768" y2="399.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="447.5" x2="768" y2="447.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="495.5" x2="768" y2="495.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="543.5" x2="768" y2="543.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="591.5" x2="768" y2="591.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="639.5" x2="768" y2="639.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="687.5" x2="768" y2="687.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
            <line y1="735.5" x2="768" y2="735.5" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
          </g>
          <rect x="0.5" y="-31.5" width="767" height="767" stroke="#E4E7EC" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <defs>
        <radialGradient
          id="paint0_radial_5036_374506"
          cx="0"
          cy="0"
          r="1"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          gradientTransform="translate(384 384) rotate(90) scale(384 384)"
        >
          <stop />
          <stop offset="1" stopOpacity="0" />
        </radialGradient>
        <clipPath id="clip0_5036_374506">
          <rect
            width="768"
            height="768"
            fill="white"
            transform="translate(0 -32)"
          />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip1_5036_374506">
          <rect y="-32" width="768" height="768" fill="white" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip2_5036_374506">
          <rect y="-32" width="768" height="768" fill="white" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  )
}

export default Page


All files on github
I've tried to add console logs in code to. Didn't help.
